# Object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mendel Hornbacher\My programs\Spaceblaster\SpaceBlaster0.0.2b.py", line 95, in <module>
    animate()
  File "C:\Users\Mendel Hornbacher\My programs\Spaceblaster\SpaceBlaster0.0.2b.py", line 53, in animate
    ship.hit(astroid_list)
  File "C:\Users\Mendel Hornbacher\My programs\Spaceblaster\SpaceBlaster0.0.2b.py", line 34, in hit
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, item, False):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1515, in spritecollide
    return [s for s in group if spritecollide(s.rect)]
TypeError: 'Astroid' object is not iterable
```

and these are the classes involved:

1. animate:

   ```
   def animate():
       ship.hit(astroid_list)
       ship.move()
       screen.fill([0,0,0])
       astroid_list.draw(screen)
       screen.blit(ship.image, ship.rect)
       pygame.display.flip()
   ```
2. self.hit (in 'Ship' class)

   ```
   def hit(self, group):
           for item in group:
               group.remove(item)
               if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, item, False):
                   self.die()
               group.add(item)
   ```
3. astroid_list

   ```
   astroid_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
   ```

If it means anything I'm running windows 8 pro.
If the above code is not enough I'll post the whole code in a comment.

Comment: You won't be able to post the whole code in a comment, btw.

Comment: But you would be able to edit more information into the question (See the edit link)

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to remove objects while iterating through them at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`spritecollide` function](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) expects you to pass a [`Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), not individual sprites.

Just test with your whole group in one go:

```
def hit(self, group):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, group, False):
        self.die()
```

Now you also avoid removing and adding items to a list while looping over it.

If you want to remove the sprites `self` collides with from the group, do so after calling `spritecollide()`:

```
def hit(self, group):
    collided = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, group, False)
    for item in collided:
        group.remove(item)
    if collided:
        self.die()
```

Instead of manually removing each item though, you could just set the `dokill` flag to True, and they will be removed from the group for you:

```
def hit(self, group):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, group, True):
        self.die()
```

If you do *not* need to know what items collided and do not want to remove items from the group, use [`spritecollideany()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany) instead; it returns just True or False and is faster:

```
def hit(self, group):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, group):
        self.die()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a single sprite to `spritecollide` when it expects to get a `list` of sprites. This is causing the exception to be thrown because your `Astroid` is not a iterable class.

```
def hit(self, group):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, group, False):
        self.die()
```

[Spritecollide documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide)

Nice little tip from the documentation is that `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` is slightly faster then the regular `spritecollide` and would be probably a better choice since you do not care what you collided with it appears, so you do not need to return what you have collided with.